# Run PC drivers silently in batch script

Tags: batch

I would like to create a batch file to update/install PC drivers after Windows installed in computer. However my script only leads to the execution of each .exe file to pop up and ask for confirmation to click INSTALL etc. Anyone can help to modify my script to make it works, please !!

```
for /r "%~dp0." %%a in (*.exe) do %%~fa
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Inside of each of those packages are the ACTUAL driver files which get installed via an <some_driver_name>.INF file.  SOME companies break the rules and do stuff "by hand" but MOST drivers will install this way.

Companies like Dell added this exe "wrapper" around the installation to simplify the process.  It is a tech support nightmare trying to tell a customer how to install a driver.  Some of these EXEs have hidden command line options to auto-install too.  Check with Dell and see if a "silent" option exists.

I suggest that you extract (and not install) the driver package "somewhere" and use that.  You will use the `pnputil` utility built into windows to install the .inf file(s).

1. Locate the inf file in the package that you need.
2. Use the command `pnputil /add-driver x:\my_path_for_intel_serialIO\some_driver.inf`
3. Use the `pnputil` utlity again to scan for hardware changes like this: `pnputil /scan-devices`.  It *might* need a reboot.  There is an option in `pnputil` to tell it to do that too.

You might need to play with the options of `pnputil` to get it just right.  Use `pnputil /?` to see what you can do.  I suggest "playing" with this tool on a box you can reinstall without losing valuable data until you get things working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to break down those EXE files into components.

Go here with file explorer:
C:\windows\system32\driverstore\FileRepository

Sort by date:
Make new of the newest date.

Install ALL your drivers manually.

A bunch of new drivers folders, perhaps dozen, will eventually appear.

Make a backup copy of ALL of the new folders.

@Señor CMasMas has pointed out how to use the pnputil command.

So pretend you have all the new folder place inside a folder called "x" (without the quotes)

```
for /r c:\x %i in (*.inf) do pnputil /add-driver /install %i;done
```

Can be done to an offline copy of windows.

```
DISM /Image:C:\Windows /Add-Driver /Driver:C:\x /recurse
```